# A measure of correspondence between ranked ordinal data

Tags: machine-learning, categorical-data, ordinal-data, agreement-statistics

I would like to find an appropriate way to measure the similarity between two sets of data with the following characteristics:

1. Both sets contain 10 categorical observations.
2. The categories observed in the two sets are not necessarily the same. That is, one data set may have 10 unique observations with respect to the other.
3. The observed categories in each set are given a rank.

What measure can be used that incorporates both the number of overlapping categories in the two sets and the ranking of the categories that they have in common.